# Plugin works on Jira 5.2.10, but does not on 6.0

Tags: file-upload, jira

Made plugin for Jira with data exchange via servlet (using FileUploadServlet).
Testing on  Jira 5.2.10 was OK, but on 6.0 there is a trouble:

> 2013-06-27 21:46:26,575 http-bio-8080-exec-24 ERROR anri 1306x1054x1 4bhuqg 169.254.57.250 /plugins/servlet/smartActDataServlet [atlassian.plugin.module.PrefixDelegatingModuleFactory] Detected an error (NoClassDefFoundError) instantiating the module for plugin 'com.polontech.jira.plugin.activity.smartact.SmartAct' for module 'dataServlet': org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException.  This error is usually caused by your plugin using a imported component class that itself relies on other packages in the product. You can probably fix this by adding the missing class's package to your  instructions; for more details on how to fix this, see https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/NoClassDefFoundError .
>
> 2013-06-27 21:46:26,577 http-bio-8080-exec-24 ERROR anri 1306x1054x1 4bhuqg 169.254.57.250 /plugins/servlet/smartActDataServlet [atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager] Unable to create servlet
>   com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException

Why? What's the difference between 5.2.10 and 6.0? How to solve the problem?
As I get, problem is with FileUpload. Maybe, there is a way to add this to my project?
dependencies are on their place:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
>         <version>1.2.1</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Error seems very vague. We cannot know what the difference is but as with every software product things change between versions and stuff works, breaks or is deprecated.

Go to the Atlassian [Support](https://support.atlassian.com) and [Answers](https://answers.atlassian.net) sites and get the answer you're looking for from the guys that develop JIRA.They'll know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

Also review all the information on https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Preparing+for+JIRA+6.0
since 6.0 is a major release

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just check the version of all dependencies: I had to use common-fileupload-1.2.2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```